# is ko.applyBindings synchronous or asynchronous?

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-2.0

Does the generated view exists right after you call `ko.applyBindings()` or does the scaffolding happen asynchronously?

Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`ko.applyBindings` is a synchronous call.

There may be cases where bindings have special code to do things in a setTimeout, but this is not generally the case.

With the addition of [components](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/component-overview.html) in [Knockout 3.2](http://www.knockmeout.net/2014/06/knockout-3-2-preview-components.html), components are asynchronous.  With Knockout 3.3, there will be an option to render components synchronously if the viewmodel / template is loaded.

Comment: Ryan, could we get an update on this answer now that components are out in 3.2?  I'm assuming that it's not synchronous if the module has not yet been loaded, but, is it synchronous if all the dependencies have already been loaded?  Thanks man!

Comment: `ko.applyBindings` itself is synchronous. components are async. In KO 3.3, there will be an option to render components sync, if viewmodel/template is loaded.

Answer (score 2):

Knockout is synchronous. Not only the `ko.applyBindings` function as RP Niemeyer already said. When you set a value to an observable property which is binded to a view, you can be 100% sure that after executing

```
myViewModel.myObservableProperty(newValue);
```

your view's been updated.
In fact, an observable property is a function and when you set a new value to your observable property you are simply calling a function with the new value as parameter: this function in its body will trigger synchronously the 'change' event (i don't know exactly the event's name).

Hope it helps.. sorry but my English is a bit rusty.